# Why won't the changes i make to my viewcontroller update when i run the app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I've got a view controller which is part of a navigation controller.  When i make changes to it, like move the location of a button or add another label to the view controller the changes aren't reflected in the app when i run it. The button remains in the same position and the new label isn't there.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saving in interface builder?

Comment: Yes, i'm saving all the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved it.  There was 2 problems.

1) I reset the Simulator. Go to: iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings. This removed the old version of the app from the simulator.

2) Because i changed the default view controller 'rootviewcontroller' to something else, i had to manually remove a reference to rootviewcontroller in the xib file.  I did this by opening up the xib in TextEdit and doing a ctrl-F for 'rootviewcontroller'.  Not sure if there is an easier way to do this in the Interface Builder, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try killing the simulator. On some machines that I work on, or perhaps specific projects, the app seems to save some state between building and running. Cmd+q the simulator and try again.